# Java: Illegal Argument Exception

Tags: java, unit-testing, reflection, illegalargumentexception

I'm getting an `IllegalArgumentException`, but I can't figure out why.

The function I'm trying to access:

```
private static Player checkEvents(Player[] players, GameMaster bananas)
```

The problematic code:

```
@Test
public void testCheckEvents() throws SecurityException, NoSuchMethodException, IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException {
    Game g = new Game();
    GameMaster gm = new GameMaster(4);
    Player[] p = new Player[] {new Player(gm), new Player(gm), new Player(gm), new Player(gm)};

    Method checkEvents = g.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("checkEvents", new Class[] {p.getClass(), GameMaster.class});
    checkEvents.setAccessible(true);

    checkEvents.invoke(p, gm); // fails here
}
```

The failure:

```
testCheckEvents(nth.bananas.GameTest)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: wrong number of arguments
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first argument to `invoke` must be an object on which to invoke the method:

```
checkEvents.invoke(g, p, gm)
```

Since your method is `static`, you can also use `null` instead of the object reference `g`.

Comment: To expand on @hjhill's correct answer, if the Method object refers to a static method, the first argument of invoke() is ignored.